# facebook app request notification not showing up in Facebook iOS app for mobile web app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-canvas, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I have a Facebook app that is configured as Facebook canvas app and a website with site and mobile site URLs

When the app sends apprequests (invitations) they only show up in the recipient's notifications in the desktop browser and not in the Facebook iOS app. This makes no sense to me as the app does support play on mobile as it has a mobile web url and so the notifications should appear in the Facebook iOS app.

How can I ensure my app requests show up in the Facebook iOS app? Am I missing some kind of configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue, but after adding a "Store ID" in the FB iOS Platform setting, notifications started showing in the FB app. Since my app is not yet in the store, I addded the ID of one of my other apps. Still worked.

Comment: Thanks! This is a bit of hack because the app I'm talking about is simply a web app and will never be a native iOS app but I got it to work by specifying it as an iOS app using the store ID a true iOS native Facebook app I also developed! This will do for now.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I will still have a problem on Android though

Comment: This worked!! Thanks so much for posting this answer; been trying to work this out for so long :)