# App requests notifications are not appearing in facebook app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've developed a web facebook app with the possibility of invite a friend via a request that appears in the notifications. It works fine in the web version of facebook but in the Facebook app (Android and iOS) the notifications are not appearing.

Some questions here in SO address the same issue but all the solutions (Canvas configuration in the developer console, permissions, set the app live, etc) do not work. In this question: [facebook app request notification not showing up in Facebook iOS app for mobile web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172592/facebook-app-request-notification-not-showing-up-in-facebook-ios-app-for-mobile) the accepted answer is to set an ID of the apple store but write a Native app to show the same content seems an overkill in time in money (Specially considering the time that the Apple store takes to accept and App).

Is there any way to fix this?, seems like before setting the canvas (Web and mobile) was enough, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually by design. The actual answer is in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.4#receive):

> Requests will only surface on platforms where the game has been
>   defined in the app dashboard as having a presence. So for example, if
>   an app exists on iOS and Android, but has no Canvas presence,
>   recipients will not see requests received via that app appear on the
>   desktop web version of Facebook.com as notifications.

Comment: I've been looking for this answer during days. Thank you a lot! I though it can be seen on Facebook webpage, while sending GameRequests from Android.